# CS50 C issues error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal

Tags: c, char, c-strings, cs50

I am stuck on figuring out how to make a proper array for C

heres my code so far:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

char text[] = get_string("Text: ");
int length =  strlen (text);
int letters = 0;
int letter = length;
while (letter > 0)
{
    letter--;
    if (text[length] == " " ||text[length] == "." ||text[length] == "!" ||text[length] == "?")
    {
        letters = letters + 0;
    }
    else { 
        letters++;
    };
printf ("%i \n", letters);

};

};
```

The error message I get each time is "readability.c:8:6: error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal"

Help would be appriciated, Thanks!

Comment: `char text[]` -> `char *text`

Answer (score 0):

The function `get_string` returns pointer to the entered string. You may not initialize a character array with a pointer. So write either

```
char *text = get_string("Text: ");
```

or as far as I know

```
 string text = get_string("Text: ");
```

Pay attention to that this statement

```
letters = letters + 0;
```

does not make a great sense.:)

And the symbol ';' after the closing brace is redundant. It introduces a null-statement that has no effect.

The if statement

```
if (text[length] == " " ||text[length] == "." ||text[length] == "!" ||text[length] == "?")
{
    letters = letters + 0;
}
else { 
    letters++;
};
```

can be rewritten like

```
if ( text[letter] != '  && text[letter] != '.' && text[letter] != '!' && text[letter] != '?')
{
    letters++;
};
```

Use character literals instead of string literals. That is for example instead of

```
text[letter] == " "
```

or

```
text[letter] != " "
```

use

```
text[letter] == ' '
```

or

```
text[letter] != '
```

Otherwise you are trying to compare a character with a pointer that does not make sense.

And instead of the variable length used as an index you have to use the variable letter. Though introducing of the variable letter is redundant. You could use the variable length instead of the variable letter the name of which only confuses the reader of the code.